# How can I get the tag attribute name using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read few lines from a file with annotations.

Line looks like this:

```
lin1 = '9272171 <category="SpecificDisease1">Adult onset globoid cell leukodystrophy</category> (<category="SpecificDisease">Krabbe disease</category>): analysis of galactosylceramidase cDNA from four Japanese patients. This difference in mutation sites may affect the clinical features of <category="SpecificDisease2">GLD</category> . '
```

I am able to get tags  with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(lin1)
s1 = soup.find_all('category')
for tag in s1:
    print (tag)
```

prints

```
<category>Adult onset globoid cell leukodystrophy</category>
<category>Krabbe disease</category>
<category>GLD</category>
```

The expected output is the following:

```
SpecificDisease1 Adult onset globoid cell leukodystrophy 
SpecificDisease Krabbe disease</category>
SpecificDisease2 GLD
```

I am not able to get much from https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html.
Can you please help what changes I have to do in my code.
I am ok with non BeautifulSoup approach too but something efficient.
Thank you.

Comment: Is that valid HTML/XML? I don't think anything can go immediately after tag names.

Comment: Not a html/xml file. Plain file but with category tags.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html). The way to use it is to import the HTMLParser class from the module and create a class that inherits from HTMLParser, as explained in the linked documentation.